# Using an Array with .where not Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

What I want to do is write a .where rails query that takes an array as an argument.

I have a object Company, and what I want the query to do is select all the Companies where the company ID does not equal one of the ids in the array.

What I have is below:

```
Company.where("id != [1,2,3]")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this

```
Company.where.not(id: [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

or using `arel` style (that I prefer):

```
Company.where(Company.arel_table[:id].not_in([1,2,3]))
```